# What's the layperson's term for words like "am", "be", "were"?

Tags: grammar, word-request

What is the most common way to refer to the group of words like "is", "be", "am", "are", "were", and "was" in English?

When I learned English as my second language, every teacher in my country called them "be-verbs", which is a subclass of verbs in general ("verb" is in my own language, of course). But after that, I noticed that almost no native English speakers call them "be-verbs". Instead, I sometimes see the word *copula* to refer to these words. Some people seem to use *linking verbs*, with which I'm not familiar at all.

I know that these words are called *copula* at least by professional linguists, but currently I'm under the impression that *copula* may not be widely recognized by the general public. So I'm interested to see the layperson's term which I can use safely.

So here are my questions:

- What is the easiest term to refer to these words?
- Do ordinary native English speakers have a chance to learn what a *copula* is, along with other grammar terms such as *noun*, *verb*, *adjective*? If yes, when and how?
- Do ordinary native English speakers consider English copulas as a subtype of verbs, or as something independent?

Comment: Re #2 This all depends on what type of school a native speaker attended, where, and in which decade! It also depends on the syllabus that was taught, I am a child of the 70s and in my school we barely studied grammar and its terminology, but I don't think I ever heard Miss Collins tell someone they had committed a grammatical error. As kids we just "knew" how to say and write something.

Comment: Note that [linking verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_verb) include other words than those derived from 'to be', like 'to feel' and 'to seem' (and derived forms).

Comment: Those are all just forms of "to be", so it sounds weird to call them "be-verbs", as if there was more than one verb.  "to be" is the copula, of course, but I don't think most English speakers know what a copula is.  (Anyone seriously interested in grammar would know, of course.)  Mostly I don't think ordinary English speakers think of the copula as anything different from any other verb.

Comment: @standon Thank you, then "the verb *be* used as a linking verb" is the best way to refer to it? Do you think almost anyone can understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These words are the inflections of the verb "**to be**" in the possible person (first, second, third), number (singular, plural) and tense (present, past) variants.

The verb "to be" is often used as a copula, but it is not the only copula, so it would be misleading to describe these words as copulae. Linking verb is another term for copula, so the same argument holds.